# Is it possible to default all MongoDB writes to safe? What is the performance hit from doing this?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongomapper, database

For MongoDB 2.2.2, is it possible to default all writes to safe, or do you have to include the right flags for each write operation individually?

If you use safe writes, what is the performance hit?

We're using MongoMapper on Rails.

Comment: the important thing isn't what version server you are using, but what version of *driver*.  If it's the latest then the default *is* safe writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of 10gen official drivers, then the default actually *is* safe, **not** fire-and-forget (which used to be the default).

You can read [this blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient) by 10gen co-founder and CTO which explains some history and announces that all MongoDB drivers as of late November use "safe" mode by default rather than "fire-and-forget".

MongoMapper is built on top of 10gen supported Ruby Driver, they also updated their code to be consistent with the new defaults.   You can see the check-in and comments [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/commit/68373a5db8aa9d8f8da2811604f17ee950792e43) for  the master branch.  Since I'm not certain what their release schedule is, I would recommend you ask on [MongoMapper mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mongomapper).

Even prior to this change you could set "safe" value on connection level in MongoMapper which is as good as global.  Starting with 0.11, you can do it in `mongo.yml` file.  You can see how in [the release notes](http://mongomapper.com/blog/2012/01/26/release-0-11-0/).

The bottom line is that you don't have to specify safe mode for each write, but you *can* still specify higher or lower than default durability for each individual write operation if you wish, but when you switch to the latest versions of everything, then you will be using "safe writes" globally by default.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to test if we are operating in safe mode?

Comment: In ruby specifically, you can call .write_concern on the connection (or DB or collection) and get back a hash specifying what the current default is for that object :w=>1 is safe, 0 is not.

Comment: For any application/driver another way to see is to increase logging detail (to 3) and look in mongod logs for line that includes { getLastError: 1.0, w: 1.0 } - that's the driver sending a request to be informed when/if the write succeeds. Alternatively, if you can try an invalid insert in your application (like using a duplicate value for a unique field) if you see an error then you are using safe mode.  If you don't get an error from driver (but of course there is one in the logs because of unique constraint violation) then you are not using safe mode.

Comment: Thanks, @AsyaKamsky! Inserting an invalid row seems obvious now, feel quite stupid. :P

Comment: don't feel bad - that's not a very good method to check write concern programmatically from your app, it's only an ad-hoc way to do it! :)

Comment: We tried using the mongo shell to execute db.write_concern, but it doesn't do anything. Additionally, we want to confirm that safe writes are applying to a specific collection. Where are we supposed to execute write_concern? Thanks, @AsyaKamsky!

Comment: That was example of ruby code - since you are using MongoMapper it means you are using the Ruby driver.  In mongo shell writes are always safe as the shell automatically calls getLastError() for you.

Comment: Thanks, @AsyaKamsky. We tried it originally from rails console using Player.write_concern where "Player" is a collection inside the database. However, we got an error message saying "write_concern" was an undefined method for the class. How can we confirm that Mongo is using safe writes?

Comment: Call write_concern on your connection object in Ruby.  See my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use mongomapper so I can only answer a little.

In terms of the database, depends. A safe write is basically (basically being the keyword) waiting for the database to do what it would normally do after you got a default "I am done" response from a fire and forget.

There is more work depending on *how* safe you want the write to be. A good example is a write to a single node and one to many nodes. If you write to that single node you will get a quicker response from the database than if you wish to replicate the command (safely) to other nodes in the network.

Any amount of safe write does, of course, cause a performance hit in the amount of writes you can send to the server since there is more work required before a response is given which means less writes able to be thrown at the database. The key thing is getting the balance just right for your application, between speed and durability of your data.

Many drivers now (including MongoDB PHP 1.3, using a write concern of 1: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php ) are starting to use normal safe writes by default and normal fire and forget queries are starting to abolished by default.

By looking at the mongomapper documentation: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/safe.html it seems you must still add the flags everywhere.